# await x.ShowAsync(); shown in Windows Phone 8.1 app Error

Tags: c#, windows, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

An exception is thrown when using "await" operator inside a function as follows:

> The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method.
>       Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int snooze;
        string audioSrc;
        int year = datepicker.Date.Year;
        int month = datepicker.Date.Month;
        int day = datepicker.Date.Day;
        int hour = timepicker.Time.Hours;
        int min = timepicker.Time.Minutes;
        int sec = timepicker.Time.Seconds;
        //   string audioSrc = alrm_sound.SelectionBoxItem.ToString();
        try
        {
            snooze = Convert.ToInt16(CustomSnoozeTime.SelectionBoxItem.ToString());
        }
        catch
        {
            snooze = 5;
        }
        try
        {
            audioSrc = alrm_sound.SelectionBoxItem.ToString();
        }
        catch
        {
            audioSrc = "Default";
        }
        DateTime myDate1 = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, min, sec);

        DateTime myDate2 = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan myDateResult = new TimeSpan();
        myDateResult = myDate1 - myDate2;
        if (myDate2 > myDate1)
        {
            var x = new MessageDialog("Invalid date or time");
            await x.ShowAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            string title = "Alarm!";
            string message = alm_msg.Text;
            string imgURL = "ms-appx:///Assets/Capture.PNG";

            string toastXmlString =
             "<toast><visual version='1'><binding template='toastImageAndText02'><text id='1'>"
           + title + "</text><text id='2'>"
                + message + "</text><image id='1' src='" + imgURL + "'/></binding></visual>\n" +
                 "<commands scenario=\"alarm\">\n" +
                    "<command id=\"snooze\"/>\n" +
                    "<command id=\"dismiss\"/>\n" +
                "</commands>\n" +
                      "<audio src='ms-winsoundevent:Notification." + audioSrc + "'/>" +
                "</toast>";

            Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument toastDOM = new Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument();
            toastDOM.LoadXml(toastXmlString);
            var toastNotifier1 = Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier();

            double x1 = myDateResult.TotalSeconds;
            int customSnoozeSeconds = snooze * 60;

            TimeSpan snoozeInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(customSnoozeSeconds);

            var customAlarmScheduledToast = new Windows.UI.Notifications.ScheduledToastNotification(toastDOM, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(x1), snoozeInterval, 0);

            toastNotifier1.AddToSchedule(customAlarmScheduledToast);
            var x = new MessageDialog("Alarm Set!");
            await x.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
    catch
    { }
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int snooze;
        string audioSrc;
        int year = datepicker.Date.Year;
        int month = datepicker.Date.Month;
        int day = datepicker.Date.Day;
        int hour = timepicker.Time.Hours;
        int min = timepicker.Time.Minutes;
        int sec = timepicker.Time.Seconds;
        //   string audioSrc = alrm_sound.SelectionBoxItem.ToString();
        try
        {
            snooze = Convert.ToInt16(CustomSnoozeTime.SelectionBoxItem.ToString());
        }
        catch
        {
            snooze = 5;
        }
        try
        {
            audioSrc = alrm_sound.SelectionBoxItem.ToString();
        }
        catch
        {
            audioSrc = "Default";
        }
        DateTime myDate1 = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, min, sec);

        DateTime myDate2 = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan myDateResult = new TimeSpan();
        myDateResult = myDate1 - myDate2;
        if (myDate2 > myDate1)
        {
            var x = new MessageDialog("Invalid date or time");
            await x.ShowAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            string title = "Alarm!";
            string message = alm_msg.Text;
            string imgURL = "ms-appx:///Assets/Capture.PNG";

            string toastXmlString =
             "<toast><visual version='1'><binding template='toastImageAndText02'><text id='1'>"
           + title + "</text><text id='2'>"
                + message + "</text><image id='1' src='" + imgURL + "'/></binding></visual>\n" +
                 "<commands scenario=\"alarm\">\n" +
                    "<command id=\"snooze\"/>\n" +
                    "<command id=\"dismiss\"/>\n" +
                "</commands>\n" +
                      "<audio src='ms-winsoundevent:Notification." + audioSrc + "'/>" +
                "</toast>";

            Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument toastDOM = new Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument();
            toastDOM.LoadXml(toastXmlString);
            var toastNotifier1 = Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier();

            double x1 = myDateResult.TotalSeconds;
            int customSnoozeSeconds = snooze * 60;

            TimeSpan snoozeInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(customSnoozeSeconds);

            var customAlarmScheduledToast = new Windows.UI.Notifications.ScheduledToastNotification(toastDOM, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(x1), snoozeInterval, 0);

            toastNotifier1.AddToSchedule(customAlarmScheduledToast);
            var x = new MessageDialog("Alarm Set!");
            await x.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
    catch
    { }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question doesn't have any image. It doesn't have any code and explanation either.  Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: await x.ShowAsync();

that method Error given

Answer (score 0):

Add the "async" keyword in the method's declaration.

for example, if your method is like -

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    await x.ShowAsync();
}
```

change it like this -

```
public async void MyMethod()
{
    await x.ShowAsync();
}
```

Update :-

Also, if your method returns a value/object, do it like this -

```
public async Task<int> MyMethod()
{
    int i = await x.ShowAsync();
    return i;
}
```

Update:-

Change your function as follows-

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

Change this to-

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

Comment: @KilerJutt I need more information and more code. I have to see your code to help you. Please "Edit" your question and provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `async` modifier to the `Button_Click` method like so:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // rest of code
}
```